# css div breaks container and drops to another below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an outer container with a column of numbers and animated text inside.

My problem is the animated text which should be beside the number column drops under the numbers and back up as it reaches the outer container and then the text breaks out.

I have tried `word-wrap:` on the animated text div to no effect. I am sure it is some sort of combination of floats, overflows and word-wrap but I cannot seem to find the right combination.

I am using typed.js for the animated text.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/gjab03dx/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `display: inline-block` from the code-block class, it appears to resolve the code block jumping below the line numbers, although the way the JS script fills and removes letters, you do get an unfortunate momentary jumping when a line is added or removed, but I think that is unrelated to this particular issue.

---

**Edit 1**

Looks like the culprit for the momentary jump is the `white-space:pre` on the span that contains the text you're writing. When I change that to `white-space: pre-line;`, the jumping issue appears to resolve itself.

I think the minimal fix then is to do two things:

1. Remove the `display: inline-block;` from the .code-block class; and
2. Change `white-space: pre;` to `white-space: pre-wrap` on the span that contains the code being written.

Here's the fiddle to show it: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/solvomedia/Lbjdq1dt/1/)

Comment: my goal is to stop the momentary jump, I have tried to set `width:` also on the code block.

Comment: Updated the answer with a minimal fix for the core jumping issue as well.

Comment: yes thank you, I had considered that so I removed it but to no effect. Didn't think to change it to `white-space: pre-wrap`

Answer (score 2):

Throw a width on there that is less than the width of the main container:
using em instead of px:

```
.code-block {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 30em;
}
```

FYI, this didn't change anything but I sped up your function and shortened the word:

```
$(function(){
    $(".code-animate").typed({
        strings: ["    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei sit atomorum forensibus, pro ad denique vituperata. His ni.</p>"],
        typeSpeed: 1,
        backSpeed: 50,
        contentType: 'text',
        loop: true
    });
});
```

working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gjab03dx/8/

I had to remove the word wrap stuff to get this to work, - interesting problem!
now you got me working on the rest!!